# Include photos in a JAR file

Tags: java

I made a Java database program for a school that contains photos for students... When I run the program via NetBeans it is OK...

But when I make the program a "double clikable application" (using Jar Bundler) and run the application: no photos are showing! (Please note that the size of the application file is about 700 KB only... When the photos' size is more than 2 MB.)

How do I to include photos in the "double clikable application" so that I can run the application with all the photos directly without using NetBeans?

I added the images directory as a source root for the project.

In fact, I right clicked on the project and selected the Properties item. I selected 'Sources' in the list that is on the left side of the dialog (this will change the content of the panel on the right side of the dialog).

I pressed the 'Add Folder...' button and selected the images folder (an entry for the images folder is added). Now, when I made the JAR file, its size became about 5 MB and not 700 KB. This is good. But when I double click the JAR file and run the application outside the NetBeans.

Two cases are considered: Case 1: if I put the JAR file in any location (on my desktop for example), the application can NOT show the photos... Case 2: I must put the JAR file in the same directory where the NetBeans project is. In this case, it is OK.

The result is the JAR file is STILL dependent on the photos folder. I need to ***embed*** all the photos in the JAR file, so it will be portable. That means if I take this file to any other computer I can run the program with all photos without the photos folder. Finally: do I need to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)`?? And how do I to use it?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the files inside a [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file and package it with the application or inside the [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file.

Later, use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)`, to get a reference to the file.
Extract the photos and show them inside your application.

Comment: Thanks, i Added the images directory as a source root for you project.

in fact, i Right clicked on the project and select the Properties item, i selected 'Sources' in the list that is on the left side of the dialog, (This will change the content of the panel on the right side of the dialog)

i Pressed the 'Add Folder...' button.. and selected the images folder... (An entry for the images folder is added).

Comment: How to use getClass().getResourceAsStream(file) in my main() ?

Comment: You can use like this: MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(). See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) for this method.

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans, put all photos under a folder, for example, `fotos`, and then make the JAR file. Now in the same location as your runnable jar file, paste the fotos folder. Open the JAR file and delete the `fotos` folder inside it.

When you run the JAR file, the classpath will be the current path of the JAR file and Java will look for the folder named `fotos` in the current classpath, as you have the `fotos` folder in the location of the JAR file. Your fotos will be loaded from there.

Comment: How to use getClass().getResourceAsStream(file) in my main() ?